# How do you get to the boss protected by two underwater currents?

Tags: blaster-master-zero

I'm at the bottom of the ocean in blaster master zero, without the swimming tank or other power up for swimming, and the way back to the surface is blocked for Jason. There is a dungeon at the top left of an area only accessible by a swimming Jason, but it is protected by a leftward and downward current. Is there a secret way to get to the necessary item, or did I need to grab it before sinking so far?

Answer (score 1):

Swim to the right of this corner. There is a room where you can make a long crawl under a current to reach a dungeon. It connects to the boss area.